# MongoDB running on windows drive setup

Tags: windows, mongodb, azure, storage

Looking to setup a high performance environment running Mongo 3.4 on windows 2016  in azure. I come from a SQL\windows background and was wondering if there are any options with Mongo to spread out the IO workload of mongod.  It seems odd that there is only a dbPath option and that you can not configure separate locations for the DB(s), opslogs and journal. Am i missing something ?

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible, using a couple of different techniques:

1. The oplog is stored in the *local* database, so you can keep it in a separate folder by using the [storage.directoryPerDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.directoryPerDB) config option.
2. The [journal](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56339/22442) is stored in a subfolder of the data directory;  you can make MongoDB save its journal files in a separate directory by preparing a [symbolic link](https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10) called *journal* in the data directory, pointing to your other folder.

Comment: Great thought! Will give it a try